# How to get the surface area of trajectory [MSC Adams]?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling

I'm not sure if the upper question is clear enough to understand but here's what I've got:

I've made a model of excavator in Adams View and got trajectory of it's motion (boom, stick, bucket) using trace marker.
This image shows pretty much what I've done {not mine, from Wikipedia}:
[image: what I mean]

Now, my question is how I possibly can get the surface area of it's uhh.. trajectory in Adams View? Or the area that is circled in purple (dashed line) - I'm not sure what to call that.

Comment: Im not sure, Its been a while since i used adams for this. But it should be possible to dump the path out for a external program to do it. Area of a polygon is pretty straight forward when moving down subtract the area of slice of segment to origin if upp add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a feature in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) that allows one to select a polygon or series of joined paths which will return the area enclosed.

I'd had to use this feature in the recent past and had found the answer in the [Graphics StackExchange.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16312/quantify-the-area-of-a-shape-in-inkscape)

[image: area of polygon image 1]

In the first image, I've roughly traced the path with the Bezier tool, then selected Extensions, Visualize, Measure Path. In the drop down box for Measurement Type, I selected Area. Be sure to select the item you wish to measure. Click Apply.

The program works slowly, presents (Not Responding) on a regular basis, but works!

[image: area of polygon image 2]

In this case, my units are set to millimeters. It would be necessary to have a reference scale object in order to have an accurate representation.